Bad CPU type in executable GHCI in VS Code terminal
I'm struggling with this problem: I've installed days ago all the haskell extensions in Visual Studio Code for studying it. Today I've opened the program, and when I've tried to start ghci the vs terminal says line 10: /usr/local/lib/ghc-9.6.5/bin/./ghc-9.6.5: Bad CPU type in executable, and doing it in system terminal doesn't cause any problem. Anyone knows how to fix it? :|

Do you have a X_86 CPU or an Mx Mac? It looks you have installed the wrong Version.... You find both Version here: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_9_6_5.html Best you install it with brew: 'brew install ghc'

X_86 CPU, the strange thing is that few days ago ghci was working... Anyway, I try to reinstall it with brew, thks

You find all versions for Download here. The best is to install it with:
brew install ghc

with
brew install ghc@9.6

you get you version.
